# Firebase javascript background service worker notification icon not show

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, iis-8, service-worker

My firebase-messaging-sw.js working fine to show background notification as it should but it didn't show the icon while notification.title and notification.click_action worked correctly.

**This is my service worker's messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler**

```
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function (payload) {
console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
// Customize notification here
const notificationTitle = 'Background Message Title';
const notificationOptions = {
    body: 'Background Message body.',
    icon: '/image/logo.png'
};

return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
    notificationOptions);
```

});

**This is where I placed my icon**
[image]

**This is the result**

[image]

Thanks for your time to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After trying several days, I fixed the problem by adding 
`{"icon":"/image/logo.png"}` inside FCM Server Post request body instead of having it inside firebase-messaging-sw.js as default.

And IIS server need to serve static content for hosted web project so that the logo.png can get as public.

**This is my updated Post Request Body** in JSON format

```
{ 
"notification": {
    "title": "New Appointment Requested",
    "body": "5 to 1",
    "icon": "/image/logo.png",
    "click_action": "<host>/subpage"
},
 "to": "token"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your image in root directory and check.

Please refer to this URL-

```
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js
```

Comment: it is not working either. :( I put it in root directory.